# How to start and stop PHP dev server with exec()

Tags: php, ubuntu

How can I start and stop PHP dev server with exec() function? I need to do this in order to automate my BDD tests.

This stops execution of my script:

```
echo exec('php -S localhost:8000');
```

So I need a way to start the server from PHP and be able to continue executing my test. And then I also need a way to stop it from PHP.

Comment: I have a function name though: suicide()

Comment: That's because exec is a blocking call. You could use something like `proc_open`: http://php.net/proc_open or `popen`: http://php.net/popen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
private function _startDevelopmentServer($pidfile)
{
    $cmd = 'cd ../../public && php -S 127.0.0.1:8027 index.php';
    $outputfile = '/dev/null';
    shell_exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
    sleep(1);
}

private function _killDevelopmentServer($pidfile)
{
    if (file_exists($pidfile)) {
        $pids = file($pidfile);
        foreach ($pids as $pid) {
            shell_exec('kill -9 ' . $pid);
        }
        unlink($pidfile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're stopping Apache. It processes the stop command, but at that point of time the server has stopped, so there's no way it can process another command because the server is not there to parse it. Write a shell script that stops and restarts Apache, then call that from your PHP code. The shell script should continue executing even when Apache has stopped.

I am assuming your server is Apache.

Comment: Nope. Nothing at all to do with apache. He's using the dev web server built into PHP 5.4. However, the basic suggestion behind what you said -- start and stop the server in a batch script outside of PHP -- is probably the correct solution.

Comment: No this has nothing to do with Apache, I am talking about the internal development web server introduced in PHP 5.4. Check my answer, I have figured this out.