# Problem switching between openresty and nginx

Tags: php, bash, nginx, openresty

I'm trying to switch between `nginx` and `openresty` with `php` using `exec`.

I use this to switch to openresty, `exec('/bin/systemctl stop nginx ; /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -p /usr/local/openresty/nginx');`

and this `exec('/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -s stop ; /bin/systemctl start nginx');` to switch to nginx.

Both work from `ssh`, however, from php I am unable to start nginx. This `/bin/systemctl start nginx` does not appear to execute. I tried executing the code from `.sh` files instead but that didn't work.

Comment: Hi, first of all starting this services will require privileges, especially that they need privileged port (that can be open only by root).

Second - can say which distro are you using? There might be multiple problems like apparmor or SELinux. Is it possible to get your php code that change service?

Is service changed put into background and detached from session?

Comment: @AlexBaranowski I am using `Centos 7` and `php` is running with root permission.

Comment: Can you try following trick.

`exec('/usr/bin/nohup $(sleep 2; /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -s stop ; /bin/systemctl start nginx) &');` . This should make subshell that detach itself from nginx.

Comment: I think this is similar to [How to start and stop PHP dev server with exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136275/how-to-start-and-stop-php-dev-server-with-exec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using this to switch to `openresty`:

```
shell_exec('/bin/systemctl stop nginx; /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -p /usr/local/openresty/nginx');
```

and this to switch to `nginx`:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -s stop; /bin/systemctl restart nginx');
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
exec('/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -s stop && /bin/systemctl start nginx');
```